# How to Fix Heroku Application Error For a Successfully Deployed React App

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

Good day. I've managed to successfully deploy my react app to Heroku. However, when I try to open, I get the following errors in my heroku logs:

```
2020-04-04T11:31:03.263548+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.176.146/
2020-04-04T11:31:03.263914+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-04T11:31:03.264020+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-04T11:31:03.264096+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-04T11:31:03.264274+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-04T11:31:03.264276+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-04T11:31:03.360569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-04T14:25:45.432183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-04T14:25:57.190700+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-04T14:25:57.190727+00:00 app[web.1]: > portfolio@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-04T14:25:57.190728+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-04-04T14:25:57.190728+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-04T14:25:59.253101+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.211.122/
2020-04-04T14:25:59.253414+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-04T14:25:59.253514+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-04-04T14:25:59.253580+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-04T14:25:59.253747+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-04T14:25:59.253749+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-04T14:25:59.349915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-04T14:28:20.178274+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kerron-king-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=d8f77821-5bd5-4d55-8b95-8fbd37c13c09 fwd="190.213.65.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-04T14:28:24.241325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kerron-king-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=c021725e-5389-452d-9601-a7c8018ab331 fwd="190.213.65.88" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is a react app, that was built using the create-react-app command. I did no webpack editing and my package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

My public folder is as follows:

```
- index.html
- robots.txt
```

The contents of those files are:
index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

robots.txt :

```
# https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

I also have 4 images that I use in the project, that are housed in the following directory:

portfolio/src/imgs

Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a configuration file for your heroku deployment? or are you using the default settings(by just pushing it to the remote heroku branch)

Comment: I'm using the default settings @LuisOsta

Comment: If nour's solution hasn't work it may be because Heroku isn't really configured to work with the webpack development server of CRA.

The solution to that would be to make a express server that serves the static files resulting from running 'npm run build' in CRA and then deploy the Express server instead of CRA directly.

Answer (score 22):

Ok, I've found the issue. The default buildpack when deploying is that of node.js. I needed to use the create-react-app buildpack (as seen below). It works perfectly now.

```
heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack mars/create-react-app
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

Comment: Glad you found the solution! I didn't know there was a buildpack for CRA, that's cool

Comment: You can also follow the manual creation of Heroku app (or changing an existing one) by manually setting the "buildpack" from Settings > Buildpacks > Add buildpack with URL "https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app.tgz".

Comment: Thank you @AndrewRadulescu. That saves me deploying my create-react-app

Answer (score 5):

If your app is already deployed you can just install the https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack in heroku settings, if still not working. Try adding a procfile with `web: bin/boot`. It works for me and hope it works for you.

Comment: Adding https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack in heroku settings works for me

Answer (score 1):

If you used create-react-app you should add a new object called engines. Inside of the engines object, you specify the versions for npm and node. To do this open up your terminal and type in:

npm -v
Press enter

node -v
Press enter

```js
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": "5.7.1",// here put your version
    "node": "9.5.0" // here put your version
  },
... the rest of the file
}
```